# Why does urllib2 not take my URL?

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I have got URLs stored in a list which are supposed to be passed to urllib2. However, urllib doesn't seem to like this very much and I just cannot see why!

here is what I have got:

```
url = list[1]
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
```

The URL is a google maps Directions Web API URL of the kind:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=[origin]&destination=[destination]&waypoints=optimize:true|[waypoint1]|[waypoint2]&sensor=false
```

Now, if I try to run this, the retrieved html always looks something like this:

```
{
"routes" : [],
"status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

Indicating that something is wrong with the passed URL. If however, I take the URL and assign it directly, like so:

```
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=[origin]&destination=[destination]&waypoints=optimize:true|[waypoint1]|[waypoint2]&sensor=false"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
```

The result will happily come through with the (for me) essential end part looking like this:

```
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : [ 2, 0, 7, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1 ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

My (hopefully not too stupid) question is therefore: why does urllib do its job when the URL is assigned directly but not if it comes from a list??

Thank you very much for your help,
J

PS: Is there a reason why the forum-software always cuts off my 'Hi all' greeting?

Comment: I would suggest that list[1] isn't the same as your string. Also, I'd suggest you don't name an array "list" since it's a type.

Comment: Cheers moopet,

in my code list[1] is not actually called that I just needed to anonymise a little ;)

Regarding list[1] not being equal to my URL: how could that be, given that I used 'print list[1]' to have python print the respective string, then copied it into place from where it then works...?

Comment: Re: "ps" - people probably edit that out since greetings and thank yous are not needed here. Just questions.

Comment: Also are you sure the value of list[1] is equal to the literal string you tried?

Comment: Well, I guess I am not :) I am suspecting it isn't, but I don't know how to test it? if I have the script use python's 'print list[1]' it produces exactly what I copy pasted. How would I test it?

Comment: Could it be an issue that the URL contains German characters, such as ß and other umlauts? I am trying all sorts of things. If I remove the waypoints and try with origin and destination alone (which don't contain any funny characters) it works...

Comment: It certainly is possible that special characters in your string could cause trouble if they're not encoded in the way `urllib` expects. I've not investigated it in detail, but in general, URLs are supposed to be ASCII when they hit the wire, so you probably need to escape the special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue!

Was pretty easy once I stepped back for a moment and thought about it again:
I did get an answer from google's Web API which means that urllib2 did pass *something*. However, it must have been sending something that didn't make any sense to the API backend. The URL containing German addresses I lucky-guessed the problem being caused by umlauts.

So I simply passed my URL through a function replacing each umlaut with its non-umlaut alternative and suddenly everything seemed to work fine.

If anybody comes accross a similar issue, here's how I solved it:

```
# Function for replacing all umlauts
def replaceUmlauts(text):
    dic = {'Ä':'Ae', 'ä':'ae', 'Ö':'Oe', 'ö':'oe', 'Ü':'Ue', 'ü':'ue', 'ß':'ss'}
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
```

Then simply use

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(replaceUmlauts(url))
```